# How to remove this breadcrumb?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am using the Hansel breadcrumb module to generate the breadcrumbs. When I visit the /user page, I get a breadcrumb that is like "Home -> admin"; what I want is "Home -> My account." I am not sure from where this "admin" is generated. I would like to remove that "admin" in the breadcrumb so that I can use Hansel to generate "Home -> My account."

Comment: Is there particular reason you're using Hansel if it does not do what you want? Have you tried any other breadcrumb module?

Comment: Yes, he has [a particular reason](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31724/how-to-use-hansel-module).